# SwiftUI - Dynamic buttons in ActionSheet?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to get my array `sizes` (which can have different values). I'm trying to loop through the array and create a `.default` button in an `ActionSheet`.

Here's the code:

```
var sizes = ["S", "M", "L"]

var body: some View {
  Button( [...] )
  .actionSheet(isPresented: $showingActionSheet, content: {
    ActionSheet(title: Text("Select size..."), buttons: [
      ForEach(0 ..< sizes.count) { index in
        buttons.default(Text(sizes[index]) { print(sizes[index]) })
      }
    ])
  })
}
```

Obviously, this doesn't work as you can't execute `ForEach` inside of the `buttons` array. How would I go about dynamically producing these buttons and their functions? Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ActionSheet` accepts an array as its parameter, so you can just `map` your `sizes` array to an array of `ActionSheet.Button`:

```
ActionSheet(title: Text("Select size..."), buttons:
    sizes.map { size in 
        .default(Text(size)) { print(size) } 
    }
)
```

Comment: what about adding some static buttons e.g. .cancel() to the dynamic list?

Comment: @lenny You can e.g. add it to the end of the array by using `+`: `sizes.map { ... } + .cancel()`.

Comment: @lenny sizes.map { ... } + [.cancel()]